# Binding a custom class as a DataSource

Tags: .net, asp.net

Say I have this class:

```
public class Student {

    private string _name;
    private int _id;

    public string Name 
    {
    // get and set
    }

    public int ID
    {
    // get and set
    }

}
```

I want to bind it to, say FormView

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormView1">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblName" Text="<% Eval('Name') %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

However, when I try to do

```
FormView1.DataSource = student;
```

I will get an error saying I have to implement iListSource, iEnumerable or IDataSource.

I don't know if IListSource and IEnumerable is applicable, and I can't find a good example on how to implement IDataSource.

This is for asp.net.

Comment: Create a List<Student> collection and add a single Student instance to that. Than bind the list instead of the single object.

Comment: FWIW the effect your trying to produce here is beyond trivial in ASP.NET MVC, model binding is one of the primary facets of it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a List Object,
Something like

```
List<Student> lstStudent = new List<Student>();
lstStudent.add(student);

FormView1.DataSource = lstStudent;
```

Comment: That escaped my mind even though I have done it before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bind:

```
new object[] { student }
```

instead.